# Display pdf from files folder(outside of sandbox) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pdfkit

I am trying to display the pdf that I had earlier saved in files folder. I am trying to create a url of the file and display it using pdfKit but the url is always nil. I am trying as following:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~uvita/Documents/Symptom%20Checker_E07DB307-667A-4BFA-A4D7-AE6F0F2AE3F4.pdf")
        guard let pdf = PDFDocument(url: url) else { return nil }
```

The pdf variable is coming nil but url is correct.

Comment: Use FileManager

Comment: Use UIFilePickerViewacontroller

Comment: @Paulw11 You probably meant `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

Comment: Apart from the fact that you cannot access URLs outside of the application container without a security scoped bookmark it doesn’t work either because you are using the wrong API. For strings representating URLs **including** the `file` scheme you have to use `URL(string:)`.

Comment: I don't want to give option to pick the file. I want to display all the files from a particular folder inside the application

Comment: @LeoDabus. Yes. I hadn't had my ☕️yet

Comment: @Panks it doesn't matter what you want. Apps are not allowed to access files and folders outside their sandbox. You have to use a file picker to allow the user to provide access to a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register (and then deregister) access to the URL before being able to access it in your app.

Something like:

```swift
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "<your_path>")
guard 
  url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(),
  let pdf = PDFDocument(URL: url)
else { return nil }

// you must always stop access after starting it;
// setting a defer block straight away is good practice
defer {
  url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
}

// continue processing your PDF and/or URL
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me